# How to change this PHP string for an image?

Tags: php, html, string, image, phpbb3

Instead of the string "Overview" I want to set it to an image, is that possible and how can I do it?

```
if (empty($lang) || !is_array($lang)) {
    $lang = array();
}

$lang = array_merge($lang, array(
    'UCP_MAIN' => 'Overview',
));
```

Comment: Where and how the key `UCP_MAIN` is used? Does it [tag:phpbb3] forum?

Comment: yes, it is a phpbb3 forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file `language/en/ucp.php` just replace the string with a full `img` tag as follows:

```
'UCP_MAIN' => '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/1" />',
```

**Notice**: This solution is tested on [phpbb3](/questions/tagged/phpbb3) version 3.0.13-PL1.

Answer (score -1):

Pass it as a path or use base64_encode to pass it as a file:

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents(path));
```